# Select cell with specific value VBA

Tags: vba, cell

I am searching the maximum value in a set range and then I need to somehow get the address of the cell with the MAXvalue or select the cell. The code I have made des not work - it returns twice the value and not the address - what is there wrong?

```
         '' set range to search in
        Set rng = Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5))
        '' find max value
        VMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)
        '' return the address of the cell with max value
        Set c = rng.Cells.Find(What:=VMax, LookIn:=xlValues)
```

Thanks for help

Comment: `c` has what you need in it - how are you trying to output it's address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `c` is a range, it has an address. Depending on what you need, use any one of these:

```
c.Address
c.Row
c.Column
```

Comment: I also thought that but when I gave e.g. `Range(c).Select` it gives me eggor of `Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed` but when I assign it as e.g. `a=c.Address` it is ok. Why I have to re-assign it?

Comment: You seem to misunderstand some basic concepts here... `c` **is a range**. You don't do `range(c)`, as you wouldn't do `range(range())`. You need to use `c.select`. Try to understand the basic concepts of Object Oriented programming, and read up on VBA object variables.

Comment: Also, did the answer help you? I'm not sure I fully understood what you needed.